# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Tags: java, sqlite, jquery-mobile, jdbc

I want to make a query  and use the value entered by the user in the edittext as condition is the where clause.
In database helper.java class:
The query is the following:

Databasehelper.java:

```
public Cursor patientHisto ( ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery (" select dateap,diagnostic,prestreatment from patients_table, appointments_table, examinations_table where patients_table.id = appointments_table.idp and appointments_table.idap = examinations_table.id_ap and ID = ?  order by name, familyname asc"  , new String[] {ExaminatFragment.value} );
        return res;
    }
```

In ExaminatFragment.java:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_examinat, parent, false);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    id_p = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.id_p_text);

    String value = id_p.getText().toString();

    getPatHisto( );
    return v;
    }   


public void getPatHisto( ) {



    showhp.setOnClickListener(

            new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Cursor res = myDB.patientHisto();
            if (res.getCount() == 0){

            showMessage("Patient history", "No patient history found");
            return;

                    }


    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (res.moveToNext()){
                            buffer.append("Dateap:"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Diagnostic:"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Prestreatment:"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n");




                        }
    showMessage("Patient's history", buffer.toString());
                    }


                }
                );
                }


public void showMessage(String title, String Message){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();

    }
```

When running the application and clicking on the button it gives me the following error:

```
01-06 10:55:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 10:55:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Process: com.example.appointapp, PID: 1952
01-06 10:55:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
01-06 10:55:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
01-06 10:55:57.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
```

Please help.. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign to a **local variable** `value` instead of assigning to the **class member**:

```
 String value = id_p.getText().toString();
```

should be

```
 value = id_p.getText().toString();
```

Otherwise `ExaminatFragment.value` will be `null` in SQL Statement

You might want to change your DB method to accept a parameter:

```
public Cursor patientHisto ( String value ) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery (" select dateap,diagnostic,prestreatment from patients_table, appointments_table, examinations_table where patients_table.id = appointments_table.idp and appointments_table.idap = examinations_table.id_ap and ID = ?  order by name, familyname asc"  , new String[] {value} );
    return res;
}
```

And not rely on a *static* field to pass that value. Your call into that method would then change to

```
 Cursor res = myDB.patientHisto(value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much the query is working but it is rendering wrong data. it is giving me : No patient history found for a patient that have a history examination. Can you help or provide a suggestion? thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you.. i've checked the table of examination using sqlite manager and found the examination row related to the id of patient I entered, but the rendering is incorrect.

Comment: It is giving me: No patient history found !

Comment: did you add debug output for the value passed into the statement?

Comment: Thank you so much , this is what I did: I just copy and paste the db method to the helpermethod.java
And in examinatfragment.java add this: String value; and change the first lines of getPatHisto into this: public void getPatHisto( ) {
 
  value = id_p.getText().toString();
 
 showhp.setOnClickListener(
    
    new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Cursor res = myDB.patientHisto(value);
      But unfortunaltely it is still giving No patient history found !

Comment: please edit your question or ask a new one - reading code in comment is very frustrating

Comment: Thank you i will be adding a new question